# I need to move the decimal places to left or right in Hive without rounding

Tags: sql, function, hadoop, hive, decimal

I am having a number (it might be 12345 or 123.45).

I need to move the decimal places to left or right in Hive without rounding.

## Question 1

```
select 1001.123*POW(10,-2);

10.011230000000001

select 1001.123/100;

10.011230000000001
```

But I want this as 10.01123.

## Question 2

But if it is a case like below then

```
select 1000*POW(10,-2);

10.00
```

Please suggest me some function or process.

Comment: It sounds like you want the `decimal` data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Hive, I could not get any function which would give me exact division without traling zeros. So I did it in Java using BigDecimal.

BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("1001.123");
BigDecimal newValue = value.scaleByPowerOfTen(-2);

OP: 10.01123

BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("1000");
BigDecimal newValue = value.scaleByPowerOfTen(-2);

OP: 10.00

Thank you for helping!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below one.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @value <> CEILING(@value) THEN Str(@value, 12, 4) ELSE Str(@value, 12, 2) END
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time.. 
I am not sure abt scale of the number where I want to substring. I canot use switch case here. 

I would be using that function in a select query, Select @value*POW(10,-2),... from  table. 

Please suggest.

Comment: @Zkhan can you please share your function where you need this logic(query). So that suggestions will more efficient.

Comment: If you don't have any user defined function for that than you should create and select this function in your select query.

Comment: on #2 comment, select col1, col2, col3*POW(10,-2) from table.
col3Value is like 123 11.23 123.23
then  Output   1.23 0.1123 1.2323

So whatever the col3 value is thr, I need to move the decimal place left by 2 digits.